# Porque não consigo criar a <div> no lugar certo?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, div, bootstrap-4

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    .navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
        font-size: 30px;
        display: inline !important;
        border: none;
    }
    #menu-exp {
        display: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggler {
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
        right: -65%;
    }
    .navbar-nav a {
        position: relative;
        color: darkgreen !important;
        font-weight: 800 !important;
        text-align: center;
        left: -80%;
        padding: 3px 0px 5px 0px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #logo-menu {
        width: 62%!important;
        float: left;
        padding-top: 2%;
        padding-bottom: 3%;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        padding-top: 6%;
    }
    #menu {
        display: block!important;
    }
}
.bg-light {
    background-color: white!important;
}
#menu {
    display: none;
}
#img-logo {
    padding-left: 23%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    width: 112%;
}
#menu1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 23.9%;
    left: 98%;
    top: 1%;
    height: 90%;
    padding-left: 2.3%;
    padding-top: 0.7%;
    border-radius: 17px;
}
#menu-header {
    position: relative;
    top: -66px;
    left: -296px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#menu-header a {
    color: darkgreen!important;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
#menu-header a:hover {
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: darkgreen;
    border-bottom-width: 6px;
}
#menu1 p {
    position: absolute;
    right: -190px;
    top: 10px;
    padding-right: 2%;
}
#menu1 {
    background: darkgreen;
    color: #fff!important;
}
#menu-container {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 30%;
}
#imageContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    background-image: url(Imagens/29170010-Close-up-of-businessmen-shaking-hands-Stock-Photo-business-meeting-handshake.jpg);
    position: absolute;
    left: -0.7%;
}
#h1-img {
    color: white;
    font-size: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 16%;
    word-break: break-all!important;
    padding-left: 10%;
}
#h1-img2 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 20%;
    word-break: break-all!important;
    padding-left: 12.1%;
}
.imageContainer hr {
    display: block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 5px;
    margin: 32em;
    padding: 10;
}
```

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../../OneDrive/Documentos/Site sem nome 2/glyphicons.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="projeto.css">

    <script type="text/jscript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>

<body>

    <section id="menu">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <img class="img-fluid" src="Imagens/Logo.png" id="logo-menu">

                    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
                        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" id="hamburger"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                            <div class="navbar-nav">

                                <a> HOME</a>
                                <a> SOBRE NÓS </a>
                                <a> ÁREAS DE ATUAÇÃO </a>
                                <a> ARTIGOS E PALESTRAS </a>
                                <a> CONTATO </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </nav>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

    <section id="menu-exp">

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row align-items-start" style="">

                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                            <img id="img-logo" src="Imagens/Logo.png">
                        </a>
                    </nav>
                    <div id="menu-container">
                        <nav class="nav" id="menu-header">
                            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">HOME</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">SOBRE NÓS</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">ÁREAS DE ATUAÇÃO</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#"> ARTIGOS E NOTÍCIAS </a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">PALESTRAS</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">CONTATO</a>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                                <div id="menu1">
                                    <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> | <span class="fa fa-phone"> </span> Fone: 11 9999-9999

                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </nav>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </section>

    <section>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="imageContainer">
                    <h1 id="h1-img"> Conte com uma equipe de advogados especializada</h1>
                    <br>
                    <h1 id="h1-img2"> em Direito da Saúde, Consumidor e Imobiliário </h1>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

    <section id="cartoes">

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <br>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1> oi </h1>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Sempre que eu crio uma `<div>` nesse código, as coisas que eu coloco ficam em cima da imagem da `<div>` anterior. O que eu fiz de errado? Estou meio confuso com essas mudanças do Bootstrap 4.

[image: Imagem]

Comment: Onde é suposto ela ficar situada?

Comment: Em baixo da imagem. No fim da div anterior, só que qualquer coisa eu coloco depois é como se eu colocasse dentro da div anterior

Comment: Pode mostrar os estilos da div `container-fluid`?

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi muito bem a pergunta, mas a classe container-fluid é um container do Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Eu penso que essa div tem `position: absolute` ou uma dessas divs do meio tem, fazendo com que ela fique por cima de quaisquer divs abaixo, tal como se ela não existisse.

Comment: Esse é um template? Porque se é, mostre o link que eu investigo melhor

Comment: O que você falou já resolveu, era o problema do absolute. OBRIGADO!!!

Comment: Publiquei a resposta, pode aceita-a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu penso que essa div tem position: absolute ou uma dessas divs do meio tem, fazendo com que ela fique por cima de quaisquer divs abaixo, tal como se ela não existisse, retire-o e ficará direito.